# Using grep for excluding words

Tags: linux, shell, grep

For example my text is like this below.

```
mykey
nice comment
...
...
mykey
not bad comment
...
...
mykey
nice comment
...
...
mykey
excellent comment
```

I am using grep such as

```
$ grep 'mykey' * -1 | wc -l
$ 4

$ grep 'mykey' * -1 | grep 'nice comment' | wc -l
$ 2
```

This can check the number of `mykey` appears and `nice comment` is succeeded.

Then I want to see where the `nice comment` is not appeared after mykey.

At first I try this ,but it was wrong.

```
grep 'mykey' * -1 | grep -v 'nice comment'
```

I want to show such as,

```
mykey
not bad comment

mykey
excellent comment
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with `grep`, but you can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/mykey/{N;/nice comment/!p;}' master.txt
```

Output:

```
mykey
not bad comment
mykey
excellent comment
```

If you only want to count number of "not nice" comments, you could still use two greps:

```
$ grep -A1 --group-separator= 'mykey' master.txt | grep -v 'nice comment\|mykey\|^$' | wc -l
2
```

Comment: THank you very much for your comment, I try this but it says, `sed: 1: "/mykey/{N;/nice comment ...": extra characters at the end of p command` and mytext is master.txt where can I set this?

Comment: @whitebear adapted the answer, please check again

Comment: THank you very much!! it can work for me, but I still not understand what `{N;p!}` means....

Comment: Is it possible can I check if does `nice comment` appear in after two lines not only next line.?

Comment: @whitebear `N` skip the line. `!` inverts the match

Comment: I see. thankyou very much!  I can learn step forward!